# How to represent a number with a repeating decimal as a ratio of integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, ratio

How to express the following number as a ratio of integers:

$10.1\overline {35}$

where 35 repeats infinetly. so:

$10.135353535353535353535353535\cdots$

Basically I did this so far

$\frac {101}{10} + (.35) *$ geometric infinite series $\left(\frac 1{10}\right)^n$

But this isn't right. What am I doing wrong with my infinite series? I want to make it correct so I can use the sum formula.

The answer is: $\frac {5017}{495}$

But I'm not sure how to get that answer.

Comment: Hint:  If $s$ is your number then $10s=101.\overline {35}$ and $1000s=10135.\overline {35}$

Comment: This is the standard way to write repeating decimals as a rational.  If you subtract you get $1000s-10s=990s=10135-101$, with no decimal involved.

Comment: If you want the geometric series way, the series you want is not $(1/10)^n$ but $(1/100)^n$

Comment: You need $1$ followed by as many $0$s as you have repeating digits

Comment: My method avoids the use of infinite series.  Since $990s=10034$ we get $s=\frac {10034}{990}=\frac {5017}{495}$

Comment: @Andrei okay i got u now i see dis I think i got this 3.5(1/99) + 101/10

Comment: Then you can answer your own question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say $x=10.1353535...$.

Then $1000x=10135.3535...$ and $10x=101.3535...$

Subtracting these both equations gives

$990x=10034$ which after simplifying gives

$x=10.1353535..=5017/495$

Comment: thx babe but i gott it alreadyyy